# Displaying children categories in current parent category (Expression Engine)

Tags: php, search, expressionengine

I need help with expression engines terrible categories system...

I have 4 main categories, each of which have children categories, these children categories have another 2-3 children category groups.

I need a way for users to search through these categories, so the best way is to display the current categories children and provide the user to go back to the last category. (basically a breadcrumb trial with multiple categories.

In a nutshell, how can I display children categories based on the current parent that is active? For example if one of my category structure was as follows:

```
Toys
     -AGE 2-5
         - Cuddly Toys
         - Small Toys
         - Teddy Bears
     -AGE 5-10
         - Lego
         - Cars
         - Dolls
     -AGE 10-16
         - Video Games
         - Board Games
         - Bricks
```

If the user clicks "Toys", this will redirect to a page with all the toys, then the user can search further by now selecting one of the children categories "AGE 2-5, AGE 5-10 or AGE 10-16. If they select one of these, they can now search further by choosing another child.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Millions of ways to do that: please be more specific. Do you want the SQL query? PHP code? what have you already tried?

Comment: Hi, The easiest way possible really. The client wants to manage the categories so it needs to be flexible. I've been trying all morning to get it to work using expression engines tags but i'll probably have to use a query.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but you should really check out buildwithstructure.com - gets around the nasty categories system. Or look at playa - http://pixelandtonic.com/playa - and use channel entries as your categories rather than ee categories. I've built dozens of EE sites and I never use the categories tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Child Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/child-categories) add-on, and also the [GW Code Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) add-on. I'm sure that one of these can achieve what you're looking to do.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a support thread with the developers outlining your desired result, they'd be best qualified to let you know if you can make it work. I'd try the Child Categories plugin first.

Comment: Also, "tried them both, can't seem to get it to work" doesn't help too much, some code samples would really help those here trying to help!

Comment: Sorry Derek, I managed to get this to finally work using GW Code Categories. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. It assumes you have something in your URLs that you can derive the category info from using [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat). The idea is to pass the Channel Categories tag a parameter based on what page you're on.

Assuming segment_1 is "toys," you could do something like this:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="{segment_1_category_group_id}"}
   <a href="{path='template-group/template'}">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```